# How to loop through data a certain number of times in Svelte

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

I've successfully connected my app to supabase - and it's fetching data from a table I've recently setup.

I've got the law-firm names appearing in a card template, so there's a seperate card for each h3 being pulled in.

I want to be able to loop through my database, and after fetching 4 sets of data (the law-firm name) I want to create a duplicate row underneath - fetch another 4 and continue this way (I'll sort out the pagination at a later date).

Any help would be appreciated as this is the first time I've used Svelte - and I've gone through multiple SO posts, as well as the svelte-kit documentation.

```
<script>
    export let data;
</script>

<ul class="flexCards">
    {#each visibleLawFirms as LawF}
        <li class="cardShape">
            <h3>{LawF.lawfirmname}</h3>
        </li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

Comment: Is your issue concerned with refetching data from the database or with partitioning the data to loop over in sets of 4?

Comment: What do you mean by "create a duplicate row underneath"? What should be duplicated (and why)?

Comment: Hi Matthias and Brunnerh - my issue was concerned with partitioning the data in a way that it would be displayed in rows of 4 - and then a new row would be created after every 4 sets of data. I came to the realisation that CSS Grid would sort this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there was no need for additional Javascript to resolve this - some css Grid did the trick.

```
.flexCards {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: You then also could make this responsive to screen size to e.g. reduce the number on smaller screens.

Comment: Thanks Brunnerh, that's what I intend on working on soon.